# Problem with files in packaged Electron app

Tags: electron, electron-packager, electron-forge

I'm trying to package app via Electron Forge. Packaging process is finishing, but after running packaged app I receive error in console (some files can't import). Have someone ever had similar issue?

[image]

I've tried packaging app with asar option and without it but it didn't resolve issue.

Comment: As the errors say, the files are not found so it means some of your paths are wrong. You need to share more that this screenshot if you want help such as your forge config and window config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by setting relative paths in build process